# Can I pass a heredoc script to Elixir from Bash?

Tags: bash, elixir, github-actions

I am playing around with the idea of using Elixir in GitHub actions workflows, because I think it would make for an excellent CI language (better than bash at least).

GitHub Actions does not have a straight-forward way to do this ([like it does with nodejs](https://github.com/actions/github-script)).
There is an action for [installing Elixir](https://github.com/erlef/setup-beam) though, so I have access to `elixir` and `iex` within the bash runtime of my workflow.

I'm thinking I could do something like this:

```
      # Install Elixir
      - uses: erlef/setup-beam@v1
        with:
          elixir-version: ${{ env.ELIXIR_VERSION }}
      # Run Elixir code via bash
      - run: |
          elixir -e "IO.puts(1336 + 1)"
```

This works. But is it possible to pass a multiline string, containing my script, to `elixir -e`?
The following does not work:

```
elixir -e <<-EOT
  IO.puts(68+1)
EOT
```

I guess I could just create a file, but for small scripts I feel like it would be cleaner to just pipe in a heredoc.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what a here document does. It supplies the text within as standand input. Presumably then you'd drop the `-e` option. (I'm obviously unfamiliar with Elixir, but this is how most language interpreters work.)

Comment: I see. `-e` means that it should evaluate code passed as a string, as opposed to looking for a file containing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use the stdin of elixir, using a here-doc is pointless.  You could however provide a multiline string:

```
 elixir -e 'first line
 second line
 third line
 '
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution within GitHub actions, but I'm still curious about how I could use a heredoc instead of a single-line quoted string with `elixir -e`.

```
      - uses: erlef/setup-beam@v1
        with:
          otp-version: ${{ env.OTP_VERSION }}
          elixir-version: ${{ env.ELIXIR_VERSION }}

      - id: main
        run: |
          IO.puts(1+1)
        shell: elixir -r {0}
```